# Search formula for cell references in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, string, formula

Within VBA, I want to search an excel formula (String) to find cell references.

Specifically I want to find the position(s) in the string where there is either a relative cell reference (ANY relative cell reference, not a specific one), or a mixed cell reference.

- I don't need to find absolute cell references, though I can just check and ignore those.
- I don't mind if the reference is on a different sheet, I'm happy to find the bit after the ! symbol.
- I will need to make sure that it doesn't find things that look like cell references in strings or sheet names or data names.

**How can I do this?** (This is the main question)

My thoughts:

I can see how I would find mixed cell references - I'm pretty sure the $ symbol can only ever come up in either mixed cell references, absolute references, inside sheet names, or inside strings (can anyone confirm that?), so with the right regular expression or algorithm you could find all those cases and then just check if it is an absolute cell reference and ignore that.

But how to find any and all relative cell references? The only idea I have is similar to the above. Beyond cell references, are there ever any times in Excel Formulas (outside of sheet names or inside strings) where there is a number following a letter? Any formula names or anything? The only other one I can think of is in a defined data name, but I'm not sure if you can use those in a formula, especially a Conditional Formatting formula). Can anyone think of any other times?

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Look into `Range.Precedents`.

Comment: Would you be interested in regex?

Comment: Thanks Mathieu. I mentioned I have a formula string, that's because it's from a Conditional Format. Still, I might be able to place the formula in an empty cell, trace the precedents, get a list of cells that are in the formula, and then search specifically for those. It's an interesting idea, though a pretty complicated one. Thanks

Comment: Hi Kubie, yes, I would very much be interested in RegEx, though I think the points about how to search for any and all relative cell references is an important one, and I don't know whether my suggestion would work.

Comment: One comment about your comments. instead of writing "Hi #Name", consider using @Name at the beginning of your comment. In your case it might be that Kubie and Mathieu never read your comment

Comment: @Pierre44, Got it, thanks.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon, Thanks, I've looked into it. Firstly Range.DirectPrecedents was a better fit for my needs. Secondly the problem is it 'only works on the active sheet and can not trace remote references' (same for Range.Precedents). And also, it turns every reference into an absolute reference for some reason. I may be able to work around those issues, I'm still working on that. I found https://colinlegg.wordpress.com/2014/04/06/excel-macro-to-find-and-calculate-precedents/ which does work on other sheets etc but doesn't limit to direct precedents, and still has the 'absolute reference' issue.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon Now I think about it, the absolute reference thing is a problem. Sure I can remove the $ and then search variations of reference and mixed ref, but I'm still going to potentially hit issues as mentioned in the question (custom formula names, strings, sheet names, etc. etc.). I really wish someone knew when those things can come up, per my question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53273781/excel-formulas-what-they-can-and-cant-contain

Comment: The question isn't so much "how" [to reverse-engineer or somehow re-implement Microsoft Excel's formula-parsing engine], but "why". I mean it's a very interesting challenge and I salute your efforts, but I'm stumped as to what problem is it that could possibly warrant a solution this complex. The cell addresses you get are absolute, because a `Range` references *that specific cell*. The address being referred to by a `Range` object isn't at the same abstraction level as the text string in the formula bar. The Excel OM/API doesn't need to expose the plumbing for that, ...and doesn't AFAIK.

Comment: What I mean is, that level of meta insight about a worksheet would be needed in an add-in that analyzes and/or optimizes Excel formulas. If that's what you're up to, then regex can *probably* work, but as you can see it gets rather cryptic, rather fast: debugging regex is very "fun". Alternatively you could tokenize/lex the string, and build a syntax tree with a handcrafted parser (or write it in C# and use Antlr to generate one for you), and then you maintain a *grammar* that describes the syntax, and consume and traverse tree structures to locate the references.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon yes, I am trying to write a form of optimization of formulas. My need is very specific - I need to find relative and mixed cell references in the formula string, so I can adjust them. My regex skills are a little weak, and in this case the variations might be beyond the uses of regex anyway, so I would probably write an algorithm; I can see the shape of that algorithm but need to confirm the rules/syntax of excel formulas - hence https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53273781/excel-formulas-what-they-can-and-cant-contain which overlaps with this question.

Comment: No regex can tell whether `=Foo` is referring to a function, or a named range. That's why a formal grammar / definition of the domain-specific language that Excel formulas are, makes things much simpler: by parsing the formula into a tree structure, you get something like `root[=]` -> `expression[Foo]` -> `identifier[Foo]`, and then you can have tree-annotating logic that traverses the nodes with the contextual knowledge that there's a named range in that workbook named `Foo`, and annotate the `identifier` node to a `NamedRangeReference`.. treating everything as pure strings will not end well.

Comment: For example your tree traversal might have found a match for a named range named `Foo`, but then the named range is defined in `Sheet2` at worksheet scope and can't be accessed from `Sheet1`, so your add-in can then flag that as a formula error. Or the name is valid and accessible, and you can then annotate the node with the `RefersToRange` address of that named range. What I'm getting at, is that parsing *correctly* is not done with a bunch of `If...Else` blocks. People write DSL formal grammars for simple calculator apps. Excel formulas are much more complex than that already.

Answer (score 2):

I wasn't sure what your use case is, but you could try something along the lines in this function:

> This project uses **[Early Binding](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/245115/using-early-binding-and-late-binding-in-automation)** - you must set a reference to:
>
> ```
> Microsoft VBScript Regular Expressions 5.5
> ```

```
Function findCellReferences(vTestVal As Variant) As Variant

    'Check if vTestVal is a range, if so, convert to string
    If TypeName(vTestVal) = "Range" Then
        vTestVal = vTestVal.Formula
    ElseIf TypeName(vTestVal) <> "String" Then
        findCellReferences = "Type-Err!"
        Exit Function
    End If

    Dim oMatches As MatchCollection

    With New RegExp
        .Pattern = "(?:^|[,!(=\s])((?:\$?[A-Z]{1,3}\$?\d+(?::\$?[A-Z]{1,3}\$?\d+)?|" & _
                "\$?[a-z]{1,3}:\$?[a-z]{1,3}|\$?\d+:\$?\d+))(?:$|[\s,)])"
        .IgnoreCase = True
        .Global = True
        If .test(vTestVal) Then
            Dim i As Long, retArr()
            Set oMatches = .Execute(vTestVal)
            With oMatches
                ReDim retArr(.Count - 1)
                For i = 0 To .Count - 1
                    retArr(i) = .Item(i).SubMatches(0)
                Next
            End With
            findCellReferences = Join(retArr, ",")
        Else
            findCellReferences = False
        End If
    End With

End Function
```

This function can accept two different data-types:

1. Range
2. String

This allows you to use this as a worksheet function to test the textual value of a formula, or you can use this to test an input string directly.

Here's the return checking a cell:

[image]

And here's what the formulas look like for the above:

[image]

This can also be used within VBA:

```
Sub Test()

    Rem: Passing a string argument
    Debug.Print findCellReferences("A1:B1, $C1")
    ' Prints: A1:B1,$C1

End Sub
```

---

## Breaking down the Regular Expression: [Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/VscXRQ/3)

```
(?:^|[,!(=\s])((?:\$?[A-Z]{1,3}\$?\d+(?::\$?[A-Z]{1,3}\$?\d+)?|\$?[a-z]{1,3}:\$?
[a-z]{1,3}|\$?\d+:\$?\d+))(?:$|[\s,)])
```

- `(?:^|[,(=\s])` Requires one of the following to occur **before** your match

  - `^` Start of string; or
  - A single character which is either

    - `,` a comma (useful in formulas)
    - `!` an exclamation (for `Sheet!` references)
    - `(` opening parenthesis (useful in formulas)
    - `=` literal equal sign (useful in formulas)
    - `\s` a whitespace character
- `(...)` capturing group that will return your value (one of three options)

  - `\$?[A-Z]{1,3}\$?\d+(?::\$?[A-Z]{1,3}\$?\d+)?` not entire row / column

    - `\$` for an absolute reference (column), followed by `?` making it optional
    - `[A-Z]` character class for any letter, `+` one or more times
    - `\$` for an absolute reference (row), followed by `?` making it optional
    - `\d` any digit, `+` one or more times
    - `(?:...)` non capturing group to match a range of ranges (such as `A1:B1`)

      - This uses the same methods as above
      - Followed by `?`, making the entire non-capturing group optional
  - `\$?[a-z]{1,3}:\$?[a-z]{1,3}` Entire Columns, such as `A:C`
  - `\$?\d+:\$?\d+` Entire Rows, such as `1:3`
- `(?:$|[\s,)])` Requires one of the following to occur **after** your match

  - `$` end of string; or
  - A single character which is one of

    - `\s` a whitespace character
    - `,` a comma
    - `)` closing parenthesis

---

Credits:


<sup>Suggestions by [tripleee](/users/874188):

 - Use Character class `[xyz]` instead of `OR` statements `(?:x|y|z)`

 - Better indention of breakdown

 - Grammar usage</sup>


<sup>Suggestions by [Makyen](/users/3773011):  

 - Support for entire rows `1:4` and columns `A:C`

 - Limit FPs by checking Excel's max column limitation `[a-z]{1,3}` *(instead of `[a-z]+`)*</sup>

Comment: Hi K. Davis, you've certainly given me a lot to look through and experiment with. Before that process I can only thank you deeply for taking the time and expending the effort. I don't know what the effect of changes @tripleee's changes to the code are, if any, but I'll look at those too.

Comment: I consulted him after I made this post - his edits are certainly welcome @JamesCarlyle-Clarke

Comment: Will this exclude bits of literal strings that happen to look like cell references?

Comment: That could be negated by [removing the `\s`](https://regex101.com/r/VscXRQ/5) from the equation. OP will just have to prevent spaces around legitimate ranges @chrisneilsen - The issue is that VBScript RegEx doesn't support lookarounds.

Comment: Hi K. Davis, that's quite a thing of beauty and it seems to find any references passed to functions eg SUM(H7:M7). I haven't tested all of the edge cases (eg custom function names with letter followed by a number, named ranges with similar). The problem is it doesn't seem to find either cell reference in 'A3+B4' (with or without the equals sign). Regular expressions is not my area of expertise so I can't immediately see how I would improve on that. I also don't really get the last comment you made above, but it sounds like you are saying I should remove any spaces other than in strings?