# Excel - Update formula references for new location

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

When I copy a cell with a formula in it and then paste into another cell on the same sheet, the formula's cell references get updated to reflect the new position (taking into account absolute, relative and mixed cell references, etc.).

Is there a way to do that formula updating in Excel VBA programatically, updating a string formula from one location to another without actually copying a cell and pasting to another?

If not, how do you do it copying one cell and pasting to another location in VBA?

EDIT: Axel has answered the second part of the question wonderfully. Is there a way to do the first part of the question, without it ever being pasted into a cell (because if I need to do a lot of these then I have to guess it could be a bit slow)?

Comment: Using `FormulaR1C1` normally there is no need for updating formula references for new location. For example `.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-1]+R[-1]C"` will always sum the cell left hand and the cell above independent of where this formula is applied.

Comment: Thanks @AxelRichter, that's interesting - but it is the updating of the references that I need and want.

Answer (score 0):

I would really suggest you should read about `R1C1`-style notation and the `FormulaR1C1` property In Excel VBA. This is exactly how `Excel` itself manages the updating the formula references for new location.

For example if you have a formula in `D5` of active sheet, then the following code will put a copy of that formula into `E6` exactly how Excel would do this in it's GUI. And the `sFormula2` will then contain the updated formula in `A1`-style notation.

```
With ActiveSheet
 sFormula1 = .Range("D5").Formula
 sFormulaR1C1 = .Range("D5").FormulaR1C1
 .Range("E6").FormulaR1C1 = sFormulaR1C1
 sFormula2 = .Range("E6").Formula
End With
```

Comment: Thanks Axel, clearly I do need to read up on it, thank you so much. That certainly achieves the second part of my question - I'm assuming it works with all the different types of references exactly as Excel does, e.g. absolute, relative, mixed, references to other sheets, references to other files?

Comment: Not to look a gift horse in the mouth, but do you or anyone know of a way to do it WITHOUT actively writing into another cell? (I have to figure it would be quicker if I were doing a lot of these)

Comment: I've checked everything but references to another file (I have to go out) and it all works exactly as Excel does.

Comment: @James Carlyle-Clarke: Doing it WITHOUT actively writing into another cell would need doing it using code having string arithmetic (or regular expressions) which implements a formula parser. Sadly there currently is not a `formula parser for Excel VBA`[1] which I really could recommend. [1] search keywords

Comment: Thanks again. I had to ask, before I do it the original way you provided, if there were another faster route but I knew it was a long shot. And yes, it's a version of that formula parser (specifically one that finds all non-absolute references) that I was looking at. Frankly, I have a pretty good start on one, and I have a second very different way of achieving the same thing (thanks to you), and I will try to post one or both in some form at the related question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53265024/search-formula-for-cell-references-in-vba

Comment: I can't say I tried it, but I found something that claimed to be a formula tokeniser at http://dailydoseofexcel.com/archives/2009/12/05/formula-tokenizer/ - could be useful for future questions